# Custom Post Type landing page producing 404 error despite having copied from a working example

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to setup a custom post type for a ClassicPress site, and I am using code that worked just fine on another WordPress site but cannot get the landing page to work. It keeps producing a 404 error.

- Spelling is correct--I doubled checked
- I named the template specifically: archives-families and single-family
- I activated this custom post type plugin in the admin
- the individual single-family pages work but not /families
- I have re-saved the permalinks multiple times with no luck

Not sure what else to try, especially since this is modeled after a working example.

```
 <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Family CPT
    */
    function create_post_type()
    {
        register_post_type('family', [
            'labels'  => [
                'name'          => __('Families'),
                'singular_name' => __('Family')
            ],
            'rewrite' => [
                'slug'       => 'families',
                'with_front' => false
            ],
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-nametag',
            'public'      => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports'    => [
                'title',
                'editor',
                'custom-fields'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
```

Comment: Maybe try `Administration Panels` > `Settings` > `Permalinks`, change the permalink structure to a different structure, save the changes, and change it back to the desired structure. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates

Comment: Tried it--didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Try adding `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'families'),` after `has_archive`... the ordering might matter perhaps.

Comment: Also, check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation

Comment: Tried that. Still nothing. This is just weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I named the template specifically: archives-families and single-family"

The issues could potenitally be the plural on archives. You should name the template: archive-families.php or archive-family.php

Comment: This was the solution! Thanks a bunch :)